# dplyr - how to recode to NA?

Tags: r, dplyr, na, recode

I'm trying the following:

```
data %>%
   mutate_at(vars(Q1), recode, "I don't agree" = 0, "I agree" = 1, "I don't know" = NA)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Q1 must be a double vector, not a logical vector
```

How can I proprely recode "I don't know" to missing values using dplyr?

Comment: Can you post a sample data using the `dput` function so that users can help you better? Thank you. Anyway, trying with a toy dataset, the problem should be in assigning NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `iris` dataset, this code works

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(Species), recode, setosa = 0, versicolor = 1, virginica = NA_real_)
```

Basically you need to use `NA_real_` instead of the simple `NA`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to pass a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(Species), ~ setNames(c(0, 1, NA),
          c('setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'))[as.character(.)])
```